# Show different image on hover in a post grid

Tags: wordpress, hover

I built in Wordpress a post grid with Elementor (or WPBakery Composer)

I want to achieve the following:

When I hover over a post-image a different image is shown. Of course each post has a different one.

I think the second "featured" image must be set via a plugin like e.g. "Advanced Custom Fields"
But how do I get the second image on hover?

Is there a plugin which gives me the option to just show a second image on hover?

https://localgirlboss.de/test/
You can see here how it should look like, but this is just a image with a background. The image is getting opacity 0 when hovered. I would like to have the same look with a grid of my portfolio-posts.

If you know a good gallery plugin, that has a similar functionality that would also be ok. I just have to be able to link to the portfolio.

Comment: The easiest way is to purchase an addon for Elementor with image hover effects. Or find a plugin that can do that for free. The hard way is to code it into your theme's template using a custom field.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right - unfortunately than there is no way to sort by date or name automatically. I will have to rearrange the grid every time a new post is created.

Comment: This has got to be the greatest reply on all of stack overflow. "Either buy what you need, find a plugin that will do it for free, or code it yourself." Wow.